# How to convert ONIX xml Short tag-names into Reference tag-names?

Tags: java, xml, xslt, saxon, onix

My XML Short tag file

```
    <product>
<a001>CRITICAL-62258</a001
><a002>01</a002>
<productidentifier>
<b221>03</b221>
<b244>9781911106050</b244>
</productidentifier>
<productidentifier>
<b221>15</b221>
<b244>9781911106050</b244>
</productidentifier>
<b012>DG</b012>
<b385>10</b385>
<b211>002</b211>
<series>
<seriesidentifier>
<b273>01</b273>
<b233>Publishers Code</b233>
<b244>181</b244>
</seriesidentifier>
<b018>Critical Teaching</b018>
</series>
<title>
<b202>01</b202>
<b203>Creative Approaches to the Curriculum in Primary Foreign Languages</b203>
</title>
<workidentifier>
<b201>01</b201>
<b233>critical.stisontest.co.uk Content ID</b233>
<b244>48452</b244>
</workidentifier>
<contributor>
<b034>1</b034>
<b035>A01</b035>
<b036>Louise Pagden</b036>
<b037>Pagden, Louise</b037>
<b039>Louise</b039>
<b040>Pagden</b040>
<personnameidentifier>
<b390>01</b390>
<b233>www.stisonbooks.com Author ID</b233>
<b244>44217</b244>
</personnameidentifier>
<b044><p><strong>Louise Pagden is a senior lecturer in teacher development at the University of Winchester where she lectures in primary languages. She has many years of experience in this field, first as a primary school teacher and languages subject leader and later as a primary languages consultant in Hampshire. During her time there she was involved in the implementation of primary languages in the 350 primary schools in the county. Louise has taught in Spain, Argentina, Mexico and India. Her research interests lie in immersion teaching and content and language integrated learning. </strong></p></b044>
</contributor>
<n386/>
<b061>192</b061>
<b064>EDU029000</b064>
<b200>2</b200>
<b065>JNU</b065>
<b066>2.1</b066>
<subject>
<b067>12</b067>
<b068>2.1</b068>
<b069>JNMT</b069>
<b070>Teacher training</b070>
</subject>
<subject>
<b067>12</b067>
<b068>2.1</b068>
<b069>JNT</b069>
<b070>Teaching skills & techniques</b070>
</subject>
<subject>
<b067>23</b067>
<b069>PFL</b069>
<b070>Primary Foreign Languages</b070>
</subject>
<subject>
<b067>23</b067>
<b069>ED</b069>
<b070>Education</b070>
</subject>
<subject>
<b067>23</b067>
<b069>PR</b069>
<b070>Primary</b070>
</subject>
<subject>
<b067>20</b067>
<b070>Primary languages; Language teaching; Foreign languages</b070>
</subject>
<b073>06</b073>
<b073>09</b073>
<othertext>
<d102>01</d102>
<d103>02</d103>
<d104><p>This book enables trainee and qualified teachers to embrace a more creative approach to primary language teaching. The first part of the book focuses on key language skills, including reading, writing, speaking, listening, grammar and phonics, while the second part examines a range of different pedagogical approaches to language teaching, including flipped learning, CLIL, ICT and overseas partnerships. Each chapter includes links to the national curriculum objectives and the Key Stage 2 framework for languages, notes on progression and assessment, implications for transition and a detailed case study demonstrating the skill or approach in practice. In addition the text critically explores up-to-date theory and research, making clear links between theory and practice. </p>
</d104></othertext>
<othertext><d102>02</d102><d103>02</d103><d104><p>An up to date text for trainee and qualified primary teachers promoting a more creative approach to primary language teaching. </p>
</d104></othertext>
<othertext>
<d102>04</d102><d104><p><em>Glossary</em></p>
<p><em>Introduction</em></p>
<p><strong>PART 1: Key skills</strong></p>
<p><span>1. Speaking and listening</span></p>
<p><span>2. Reading </span></p>
<p><span>3. Writing</span></p>
<p><span>4. Getting to grips with grammar</span></p>
<p><span>5. Phonics</span></p>
<p><strong>PART 2: Contexts for learning</strong></p>
<p><span>6. Cross-curricular links: music and arts; drama and role play</span></p>
<p><span>7. CLIL and immersion</span></p>
<p><span>8. Languages in the digital age</span></p>
<p><span>9. Enquiry based learning</span></p>
<p><span>10. Partnerships and exchanges</span></p>
<p><em>Key websites and sources of support</em></p>
<p><em>Bibliography</em></p>
<p><em>Index</em></p>
</d104>
</othertext>
<othertext>
<d102>18</d102>
<d104>
<p>This book enables trainee and qualified teachers to embrace a more creative approach to primary language teaching. The first part of the book focuses on key language skills, including reading, writing, speaking, listening, grammar and phonics, while the second part examines a range of different pedagogical approaches to language teaching, including flipped learning, CLIL, ICT and overseas partnerships. Each chapter includes links to the national curriculum objectives and the Key Stage 2 framework for languages, notes on progression and assessment, implications for transition and a detailed case study demonstrating the skill or approach in practice. In addition the text critically explores up-to-date theory and research, making clear links between theory and practice. </p>
</d104>
</othertext>
<productwebsite>
<b367>01</b367>
<f123>www.criticalpublishing.com</f123>
</productwebsite>
<imprint>
<b241>02</b241>
<b242>Proprietary</b242>
<b243>CPC</b243>
<b079>Critical Publishing</b079>
</imprint>
<publisher>
<b291>01</b291>
<b081>Critical Publishing</b081>
</publisher>
<b209>Northwich</b209>
<b083>GB</b083>
<b394>02</b394>
<b003>20170120</b003>
<salesrights>
<b089>01</b089>
<b388>WORLD</b388>
</salesrights>
<relatedproduct>
<h208>06</h208>
<productidentifier>
<b221>15</b221>
<b244>9781911106036</b244>
</productidentifier>
</relatedproduct>
<relatedproduct>
<h208>06</h208>
<productidentifier>
<b221>15</b221>
<b244>9781911106043</b244>
</productidentifier>
</relatedproduct>
<relatedproduct>
<h208>13</h208>
<productidentifier>
<b221>15</b221>
<b244>9781911106029</b244>
</productidentifier>
</relatedproduct>
<supplydetail>
<j137>NBN International</j137>
<j396>10</j396>
<j142>20170113</j142>
<price>
<j148>01</j148>
<j151>26.00</j151>
<j152>EUR</j152>
</price>
<price>
<j148>02</j148>
<j151>22.00</j151>
<j152>GBP</j152>
<j153>S</j153>
<j154>20.0</j154>
<j155>18.50</j155>
<j156>3.50</j156>
</price>
</supplydetail>
<supplydetail>
<j137>International Specialized Book Services</j137>
<j270>1-800-944-6190</j270><j272>customerservice@isbs.com</j272>
<j138>US</j138>
<j396>10</j396>
<j142>20170113</j142>
<price>
<j148>01</j148>
<j151>33.00</j151>
<j152>USD</j152>
</price>
</supplydetail>
</product>
```

I want to convert this short tag-names to reference tag-names. To convert to short tag-names i tried this

I Created one folder and i placed the xml files and jar files into it. For conversion i found a jar named Saxon.jar. I opened my command prompt, in that i came to wherever i placed my file.

E:\Arunselvan> java -jar saxon9.jar "criticalonix.xml" switch-onix-tagnames-2.0.xsl result-document="" dtd-path ="ONIX_BookProduct_3.0_reference.dtd"
  If i give this Error will come for me as: Bad param = value pair on command line.
I placed the command prompt image with this

My Screenshot is here
[Screenshot of short tag to reference tag conversion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KkziN.png)

I want the output file as like this Reference tag-names

```
<Product>
      <RecordReference>1512722278</RecordReference>
      <NotificationType>04</NotificationType>
      <ProductIdentifier>
         <ProductIDType>02</ProductIDType>
         <IDValue>1512722278</IDValue>
      </ProductIdentifier>
      <ProductIdentifier>
         <ProductIDType>03</ProductIDType>
         <IDValue>9781512722277</IDValue>
      </ProductIdentifier>
      <ProductIdentifier>
         <ProductIDType>15</ProductIDType>
         <IDValue>9781512722277</IDValue>
      </ProductIdentifier>
      <ProductForm>BC</ProductForm>
      <ProductFormDetail>B102</ProductFormDetail>
      <ProductFormFeature>
         <ProductFormFeatureType>02</ProductFormFeatureType>
         <ProductFormFeatureDescription>CRE</ProductFormFeatureDescription>
      </ProductFormFeature>
      <TitleDetail>
         <TitleType>01</TitleType>
         <TitleElement>
            <TitleElementLevel>01</TitleElementLevel>
            <TitleText>Everyday Evangelism</TitleText>
            <SubTitle> Practical Tips to Use Today</SubTitle>
         </TitleElement>
      </TitleDetail>
      <Contributor>
         <SequenceNumber>1</SequenceNumber>
         <ContributorRole>A01</ContributorRole>
         <PersonName>Laura Yang </PersonName>
         <PersonNameInverted>Yang, Laura</PersonNameInverted>
         <NamesBeforeKey>Laura </NamesBeforeKey>
         <KeyNames>Yang</KeyNames>
      </Contributor>
      <EditionVersionNumber>20160205204457</EditionVersionNumber>
      <Language>
         <LanguageRole>01</LanguageRole>
         <LanguageCode>eng</LanguageCode>
      </Language>
      <NumberOfPages>96</NumberOfPages>
      <Illustrations>
         <IllustrationType>01</IllustrationType>
         <IllustrationTypeDescription>1:B&amp;amp;W 5.5 x 8.5 in or 216 x 140 mm (Demy 8vo) Perfect Bound on Creme w/Gloss Lam</IllustrationTypeDescription>
      </Illustrations>
      <Subject>
         <MainSubject />
         <SubjectSchemeIdentifier>10</SubjectSchemeIdentifier>
         <SubjectCode>REL012070</SubjectCode>
         <SubjectHeadingText>Religion : Christian Life - Personal Growth</SubjectHeadingText>
      </Subject>
      <Subject>
         <SubjectSchemeIdentifier>10</SubjectSchemeIdentifier>
         <SubjectCode>REL012100</SubjectCode>
         <SubjectHeadingText>Religion : Christian Life - Relationships</SubjectHeadingText>
      </Subject>
      <Subject>
         <SubjectSchemeIdentifier>10</SubjectSchemeIdentifier>
         <SubjectCode>REL012120</SubjectCode>
         <SubjectHeadingText>Religion : Christian Life - Spiritual Growth</SubjectHeadingText>
      </Subject>
      <TextContent>
         <TextType>03</TextType>
         <ContentAudience>00</ContentAudience>
         <Text textformat="02"><![CDATA[<p>Written by an "everyday" Christian, this book contains simple, straightforward suggestions for sharing your faith.  Everyday Evangelism empowers you to tell others about Christ today.<p> 

<p>Discover new ideas and practical ways to share the gospel in your daily life.  Interspersed with scripture, the tips are grouped into eleven categories-for example:  "Super Simple," "Critical Conversation," and "Often-Forgotten."<p>

<p>Experience the exhilarating joy that God intends for you by sharing the gospel.  Use Everyday Evangelism as a tool to unleash the power of the Holy Spirit within you to "go and make disciples of all nations" (Matthew 28:19).</p>]]></Text>
      </TextContent>
      <SupportingResource>
         <ResourceContentType>01</ResourceContentType>
         <ContentAudience>00</ContentAudience>
         <ResourceMode>03</ResourceMode>
         <ResourceVersion>
            <ResourceForm>02</ResourceForm>
            <ResourceVersionFeature>
               <ResourceVersionFeatureType>01</ResourceVersionFeatureType>
               <FeatureValue>D502</FeatureValue>
            </ResourceVersionFeature>
         </ResourceVersion>
         <ResourceLink>http://image-hub.lightningsource.com/2011-04-01/Images/front_cover/x/sku/1512722278.jpg</ResourceLink>
      </SupportingResource>
      <SupportingResource>
         <ResourceContentType>02</ResourceContentType>
         <ContentAudience>00</ContentAudience>
         <ResourceMode>03</ResourceMode>
         <ResourceVersion>
            <ResourceForm>02</ResourceForm>
            <ResourceVersionFeature>
               <ResourceVersionFeatureType>01</ResourceVersionFeatureType>
               <FeatureValue>D502</FeatureValue>
            </ResourceVersionFeature>
         </ResourceVersion>
         <ResourceLink>http://image-hub.lightningsource.com/2011-04-01/Images/back_cover/x/sku/1512722278.jpg</ResourceLink>
      </SupportingResource>
      <PublishingDetail>
         <Imprint>
            <ImprintName>Westbow Press</ImprintName>
         </Imprint>
         <Publisher>
            <PublisherName>AuthorHouse</PublisherName>
         </Publisher>
      </PublishingDetail>
      <PublishingDate>
         <PublishingDateRole>01</PublishingDateRole>
         <DateFormat>00</DateFormat>
         <Date>20160205</Date>
      </PublishingDate>
      <Measure>
         <MeasureType>01</MeasureType>
         <Measurement>8.50</Measurement>
         <MeasureUnitCode>in</MeasureUnitCode>
      </Measure>
      <Measure>
         <MeasureType>02</MeasureType>
         <Measurement>5.50</Measurement>
         <MeasureUnitCode>in</MeasureUnitCode>
      </Measure>
      <Measure>
         <MeasureType>03</MeasureType>
         <Measurement>0.23</Measurement>
         <MeasureUnitCode>in</MeasureUnitCode>
      </Measure>
      <Measure>
         <MeasureType>08</MeasureType>
         <Measurement>0.294</Measurement>
         <MeasureUnitCode>lb</MeasureUnitCode>
      </Measure>
      <ProductSupply>
         <Market>
            <Territory>
               <CountriesIncluded>IN</CountriesIncluded>
            </Territory>
            <SupplyDetail>
               <Supplier>
                  <SupplierRole>07</SupplierRole>
                  <SupplierName>Lightning Source Inc.</SupplierName>
               </Supplier>
               <ReturnsConditions>
                  <ReturnsCodeType>02</ReturnsCodeType>
                  <ReturnsCode>N</ReturnsCode>
               </ReturnsConditions>
               <ProductAvailability>20</ProductAvailability>
               <SupplyDate>
                  <SupplyDateRole>08</SupplyDateRole>
                  <DateFormat>00</DateFormat>
                  <Date>20160205</Date>
               </SupplyDate>
               <Stock>
                  <PackQuantity>72</PackQuantity>
               </Stock>
               <Price>
                  <PriceType>01</PriceType>
                  <DiscountCoded>
                     <DiscountCodeType>02</DiscountCodeType>
                     <DiscountCodeTypeName>LSI</DiscountCodeTypeName>
                     <DiscountCode>36</DiscountCode>
                  </DiscountCoded>
                  <PriceAmount>9.95</PriceAmount>
                  <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
               </Price>
            </SupplyDetail>
         </Market>
      </ProductSupply>
   </Product>
```

Answer (score 2):

1) You cannot have whitespace before and after equals sign("=") in Windows command line. So it should be

```
dtd-path="ONIX_BookProduct_3.0_reference.dtd"
```

rather than

```
dtd-path ="ONIX_BookProduct_3.0_reference.dtd"
```

This is why you get "Bad param = value pair" error

2) Your input XML contains ampersand(&) which is a reserved character in XML format. Replace it with `&amp;` entity

3) Apparently this DTD is not found on this address. You should download all required DTDs:

- ONIX_BookProduct_3.0_reference.dtd
- ONIX_BookProduct_CodeLists.dtd
- ONIX_XHTML_Subset.dtd

Which can be found e.g. here:
http://www.editeur.org/files/ONIX%203/ONIX_BookProduct_DTDs+codes_Issue_33.zip

And then you can point to local files in your DTD declaration.
I also think your input file should contain DTD declaration and ONIX release info:

```
<?xml version=1.0 encoding=UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE ONIXmessage SYSTEM "ONIX_BookProduct_3.0_reference.dtd">
<ONIXmessage release="3.0">
...
(your original XML short tag input)
...
</ONIXmessage>
```

This declaration is correct assuming that you unpacked DTDs to the same directory.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to use the stylesheet http://www.editeur.org/files/ONIX%203/switch-onix-tagnames-2.0.xsl then it looks as if it takes some parameters and the one named `result-document` is supposed to be the name of your result file so you would need to decide on that name and pass it in. An empty string as the result file name won't work.

So try

```
java -jar saxon9.jar criticalonix.xml switch-onix-tagnames-2.0.xsl result-document=result.xml dtd-path=ONIX_BookProduct_3.0_reference.dtd
```

Comment: I tried this in my console. It shows message as Error. java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://www.editeur.org/onix/2.1/short/onix-international.dtd. Transformation failed : Run time errors were reported

Comment: I am afraid I am not familiar with that document format you are working with. The stylesheet tries to construct a DTD URI based on parameters and values in the input XML, I don't know which values would be appropriate or are required for the format you have or the format you want. My answer is mainly meant to show the use of Saxon, hopefully some seeing the `onyx` tag can help you with the right DTD, if you can't figure it out yourself.

Comment: You cannot use the DTD hosted on editeur.org any longer  (since the end of 2014), but have to set up your own on a local server. Instructions on how can be found here: http://www.editeur.org/files/ONIX%202.1/ONIX_2.1_local_DTD_and_XSD_instructions.pdf